# Extract an url link "only" with the ".php.com" by regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

Trying to extract an url link "only" with the ".php.com" (i.e www.sample.php.com) by regular expression, it is not able to extract and identify specific url with (.php.com ) as the following code. Please help and advise me if you got an idea. Thanks in advances.

The following code is able to extract an http or https url , but not able to identify and extract exactly the url only with php.com (i.e www.sample.php.com). How am I supposed to modify the following regular expression to extract the url with ( php.com ) only?

http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+

<> Only extract url with php.com (www.sample.php.com) , not (www.sample.com or other)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a positive lookahead which asserts that one of the URL components is `PHP`:

```
http[s]?://(?=.*\bphp\.com\b)(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+
            ^^^ change is here
```

### Demo

Comment: thanks for your quick response. In addition, is there an effective ways to learn regular expression. Thanks a millions

Comment: @IvanTo Answer regex questions on Stack Overflow.  I'm even kidding with you; it will force you to learn the entire regex API backwards and forwards, and be quick about summoning up how to solve a regex problem.

Comment: OP ask to match only  `php.com` and example shows full match for `http://www.google.com.php`  also, Please correct me if i understand question wrongly. Thanks!